# $x = $_POST['something'];

Tags: php, web

I have one question about php. I don't know hot to solve it. When wrote code like this `$x = $_POST['something'];` It is error. And when I wrote code like this,

```
if (isset($_POST['something'])) {
  $x = $_POST['something'];
 }
```

everything is fine. I don't know why? Can anyone explain me which is correct way? Sorry for bad english

Comment: `isset()` function is used to check if a variable is set. The second version checks if the variable is set **before** trying to use  it -- so, you wouldn't get an error. However, you could have found out the answer to this question with very little amount of research efforts. Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking. Be sure to check the **[ask]**, too.

Comment: Did you read the manual for isset()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: That notice indicates that the expected input variable was not present. With your `if`/`isset` wrapping you hide that message; but will get the same issue later on if you try to access `$x`. Therefore the terneray probe `?:` and assignment for silent substitution is commonly used, or `@` for keeping a log entry in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's not an error, but just a notice. It would be displayed if you're error_reporting is set to E_ALL or similar. It basically tells you that the variable is not set yet, very useful in case you have a typo or something.

You can use the if(isset()) thing, or just tell PHP that you want to disable such warning by using @

```
$x = @$_POST['something'];
```

Comment: There are very few, if any good reasons to use `@`.

Comment: @lonesomeday isn't `@` considered terribly slow?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, very slow, and prone to disguising error messages that in reality you want to be able to see.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4, `@` has near-to-zero performance impact *when no error happen*. On specific circumstances (like optional properties, session data... when the data is usually present but may be missing, without it being an error), it may be interesting, to greatly reduce the amount of code. As a quick example, `$prop = isset($obj->prop) ? $obj->prop : null` versus `$prop = @$obj->prop`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['something']` will give an error if that variable is unassigned (ie doesn't have a value). `isset()` checks to see if the variable is unassigned and will do nothing if that is the case. Therefore, the error you're getting stems from the fact that the $_POST superglobal has no variable in it called "something"

Comment: thank you all for helping. if I want to enter information in <input> tag, is it best way? if(isset($_POST['something'])){$x = $_POST['something']; echo $x;} <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST"> <input type="text" name="something" /><input type="submit" value="click" /> </form>. please write best variants, which is more correct. sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $_POST['something'] may not be set, i.e. this variable may not exist (it is an element in an array, so it can be seen somehow as a variable, for simplicity, even if this is not 100% correct).

If you add the condition

```
 if(isset($_POST['something']))
```

, then the assignment is made only when $_POST['something'] is set. So, you are sure that you can make that assignment.